# REACT: How can I download existing PDF files from my project folder?

Tags: reactjs, pdf, download

I have tried it like so:

```
<a    
  href="./cv.pdf"
  download
>
  download
</a>
```

[That's what I have in this case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g10lC.png)

Can someone help with the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First import your PDF file like that:

```
import cv from "./cv.pdf"
```

Then put it in the href attribute like that:

```
<a href={cv} download="pavel_cv"> Download My CV </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue myself, literally a few minutes ago, and I found two solutions to this: Download the file or open it in a new tab and allow the user to decide if they want to download it or not.

A quick note: the file I have is located in the `/public/data` folder of my project, since I treat it as a static asset.

1. Download the file:

```html
<a
   href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 'data/random_file.pdf'}
   download='random_file.pdf'
>
   <button>Download Random File</button>
</a>
```

2. Open the file in a new tab for the user to view or download.

```html
<a
   href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 'data/random_file.pdf'}
   target='_blank'
   rel='noopener noreferrer'
>
   <button>Open Random File</button>
</a>
```

Also, it might be a bit late to mention but I am extremely new to web development and React so please take this info with a grain of salt. And I hope this solution works for you too, or at least points you in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

Download File in React.js
To download a file with React.js, we can add the download attribute to an anchor element.

For instance, we can write:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <a     href="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"
        download
      >
        Click to download
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

We just add the download prop to do the download.

If we don’t want to use an anchor element, we can also use the file-saver package to download our file.

To install it, we run:

```
npm i file-saver
```

Then we can call the saveAs function from the package by writing:

```
import React from "react";
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";

export default function App() {
  const saveFile = () => { saveAs("https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf",
      "example.pdf"
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={saveFile}>download</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The first argument is the URL to download and the 2nd argument is the file name of the downloaded file.

Comment: As I said, I need to download a file from my project, not from other resources